# Recursive function to count all items in a nested list?

Tags: python, list, recursion, nested

I'm trying to create a method that will count all the items in a nested list. So `count([[3, 2] , [2]]) == 3`. However, it's a Class attribute so I can't just simply do:

```
def count(L, target):
    s = 0
    for i in L: 
        if isinstance(i, list): 
            s += count(i, target)
        else: 
            if i == target: 
                s += 1

    return s
```

Rather, I tried to do this, but I get a max recursion depth error. I'm not sure why. Before you look at the code, there's a few things to keep in mind: (1) I expect the base list given to only contain lists so it will have the format: `[ [], ]`. Also (2) the sub lists will not contain anything except items: `[ [item, item], [item] ]` :

```
def count(self, stack=None):
    n = 0
    if stack:
        n += len(stack)
    else:
        for i in self._items:
            if isinstance(i, list):
                n += self.count(i)

    return n
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    if stack:
```

Empty lists are considered false in a boolean context. You want `if stack is not None`.

Why use recursion, though? You don't need it.

```
def count(self):
    return sum(len(item) for item in self._items)
```

Comment: Lmao ... this is what happens when I learn a new concept and try to apply it to everything. What an easy solution. I appreciate you knocking my head back into gear :P

Answer (score 0):

If your lists are only nested one level deep, this is easy.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = items

    def count(self):
        return sum(len(x) for x in self.items)

a = MyClass([[3,2],[2]])
b = MyClass([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7],[]])
print(a.count()) # 3
print(b.count()) # 7
```